# autocomplete search not trigger auto fill fo other input fields

Tags: javascript, php, autocomplete, autofill

I am trying to implement autofill with autocomplete. My form consist of three input fields (UserID, Last Nam and First name)User ID is trigger field and auto complete successfully. But i am trying when I select from auto complete list, it should autofill values in other two fields which are first and last name). When I manually enter User ID, then First last name autofill worked fine, but when I select from list, then no autofill working.

Here is my complete code

```
    <label>User Id</label>
    <input type = "text" name="user_id"
        id='user_id' class='form-control'
        placeholder='Enter user id'
        onchange="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
    <div id="countryList"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#user_id').keyup(function() {
    
        var query = $(this).val();
        
        if (query != '') {
        
            $.ajax({
                url: 'searchCountry.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#countryList').fadeIn();
                    $('#countryList').html(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('#countryList').fadeOut();
            $('#countryList').html('');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
        $('#user_id').val($(this).text());
        $('#countryList').fadeOut();
    });

    $('#addCountryForm').submit(function(event) {
    
        event.preventDefault();
        var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addCountry.php',
            data: {
                user_id: user_id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#countryList').hide();
                $('#message').html(response).show();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name"
                id="first_name" class="form-control"
                placeholder='First Name'
                value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name"
                id="last_name" class="form-control"
                placeholder='Last Name'
                value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<script>

// onkeyup event will occur when the user
// release the key and calls the function
// assigned to this event
function GetDetail(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
        return;
    }
    else {

        // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            // Defines a function to be called when
            // the readyState property changes
            if (this.readyState == 4 &&
                    this.status == 200) {
                
                // Typical action to be performed
                // when the document is ready
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                // Returns the response data as a
                // string and store this array in
                // a variable assign the value
                // received to first name input field
                
                document.getElementById
                    ("first_name").value = myObj[0];
                
                // Assign the value received to
                // last name input field
                document.getElementById(
                    "last_name").value = myObj[1];
            }
        };

        // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);
        
        // Sends the request to the server
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

````
// Get the user id
$user_id = $_REQUEST['user_id'];

// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gfg");

if ($user_id !== "") {
    
    // Get corresponding first name and
    // last name for that user id   
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name,
    last_name FROM userdata WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    // Get the first name
    $first_name = $row["first_name"];

    // Get the first name
    $last_name = $row["last_name"];
}

// Store it in a array
$result = array("$first_name", "$last_name");

// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
?>   ```
````

Comment: The `onchange` isn't triggering when you change value via Javascript. Try to call `GetDetails` from inside the `$(document).on('click', 'li', function`

Comment: Update your `on('click'` function like so. 

`$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {

        $('#user_id').val($(this).text());

        GetDetail($(this).text());

        $('#countryList').fadeOut();

    });`

Answer (score 0):

1. I added an oninput attribute to the User ID input field to call the GetDetail function whenever the input value changes. This ensures that the autofill functionality works when selecting from the autocomplete list.

. Assuming the server response contains the properties first_name and last_name, the updated code assigns the values directly to the corresponding input fields using myObj.first_name and myObj.last_name.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control" placeholder='User ID' value="" oninput="GetDetail(this.value)">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder='First Name' value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder='Last Name' value="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function GetDetail(str) {
    if (str.length === 0) {
        document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("last_name").value = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                document.getElementById("first_name").value = myObj.first_name;
                document.getElementById("last_name").value = myObj.last_name;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gfg.php?user_id=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: in gfg file, i defined array, $result = array("$first_name", "$last_name");